# how to copy the parent node and all the child nodes of that parent with specific attribute should be present both in parent and child

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

i have this xml file....i have to check the status of SE/SSE ...if it is active then it will get inside the Details tag....it will read the status...if it is active then it will read the details tag , unless it ll discard that details node. Like that if the SSE status is "InACTIVE", no need to read inside that Node.

```
<Employees>
<Employee>
    <SE>
        <Name>bikash</Name>
        <dept>DY</dept>
        <status>ACTIVE</status>
     <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>ACTIVE</status>
        <address>India</address>
        <streetNo>19</streetNo>
     </Details>
     <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>InACTIVE</status>
        <address>CHINA</address>
        <streetNo>20</streetNo>
     </Details>
     <area>BLORE</area>
     <SEIdCount>1</SEIdCount>
  </SE>
  <SSE>
        <status>InACTIVE</status>
     <emplNo>23</emplNo>
     <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>InActive</status>
        <absent>y</absent>
     </Details>
     <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>Active</status>
        <name>anu</NAME>
     </Details>
    <area>CHN</area>
    <SEIdCount>2</SEIdCount>
  </SSE>
 </Employee> 
</Employees>
```

My Expected response is this

```
<Employees>
<Employee>
    <SE>
        <Name>bikash</Name>
        <dept>DY</dept>
        <status>ACTIVE</status>
     <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>ACTIVE</status>
        <address>India</address>
        <streetNo>19</streetNo>
     </Details>
     <area>BLORE</area>
     <SEIdCount>1</SEIdCount>
  </SE>
 </Employee> 
</Employees>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where is the `</Employee>` closing tag? Does your input contain more than one employee? If yes, please edit the example to reflect this.

Comment: sorry, after SSE tag...

</Employee> 
</Employees>

Comment: i have written like this

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <xsl:variable name="criteria" select="Employees/Employee"/>
   <xsl:for-each select="$criteria/child::*">
      <xsl:if test="current()/status = 'Active'">
         <xsl:for-each select="current()/Details">
            <xsl:if test="current()/status = 'Active'">
               <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Now did you understand what i want to ask....

Comment: Why do you ask? Did you answer any of my questions? No. So no.

Comment: There is only one employee....and that is after SSE tag..
<Employee>
<SE>
</SE>
<SSE>
</SSE>
</Employee>

Comment: what else you want to know??

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Employees">
    <Employees>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee/SE">
            <Employee>
                <SE>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Name | dept | status | Details[status='Active'] | area | SEIdCount"/>
                </SE>
            </Employee> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </Employees>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a **well-formed XML input**:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <SE>
      <Name>bikash</Name>
      <dept>DY</dept>
      <status>Active</status>
      <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>Active</status>
        <address>India</address>
        <streetNo>19</streetNo>
      </Details>
      <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>InACTIVE</status>
        <address>CHINA</address>
        <streetNo>20</streetNo>
      </Details>
      <area>BLORE</area>
      <SEIdCount>1</SEIdCount>
    </SE>
    <SSE>
      <status>InACTIVE</status>
      <emplNo>23</emplNo>
      <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>InActive</status>
        <absent>y</absent>
      </Details>
      <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>Active</status>
        <name>anu</name>
      </Details>
      <area>CHN</area>
      <SEIdCount>2</SEIdCount>
    </SSE>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

this will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <SE>
      <Name>bikash</Name>
      <dept>DY</dept>
      <status>Active</status>
      <Details dataStr="list">
        <status>Active</status>
        <address>India</address>
        <streetNo>19</streetNo>
      </Details>
      <area>BLORE</area>
      <SEIdCount>1</SEIdCount>
    </SE>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

### Note: XML is case-sensitive:

`select="Name"` will **not** select `<name>`, and "Active" is **not** the same thing as "ACTIVE".

Answer (score -1):

Using XSLT 1.0
You can also try this one out if you don't have the number child nodes within SE node fixed

```
  <xsl:template match="/*/Employee">
    <Employees>
      <Employee>
        <SE>
          <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="status='ACTIVE'">
                <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="local-name(.)='Details' and ./status='ACTIVE'">
                      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="local-name(.)='Details' and ./status='InACTIVE'"/>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </SE>
      </Employee>
    </Employees>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable comments.....i got the solution by referring your comments.

Thanks @Saurav...thnx a lot

Comment: I want to add 365 days to today's date, in my xslt i am printing today's date like this "<xsl:value-of select="SimpleDateFormat:format($date,$dateTime)"/>"